# set the div based on current height of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

How can i set the `height` of `div.outer` to set it height based on the height of `table`.
I have tried to remove `overflow: auto;` to remove the scrolls on `div.body` but some of rows are not showing and i dont want that to happen, so how can i adjust the height?

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q5abp8tr/3/) to see full codes and note that i also include `tableutils.js`. I guess there are codes on tableutils.js that can modify but dont know how to start.

Any help is so much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I'd imagine you could do it with JavaScript/jQuery. Maybe something like:

```
var tableHeight = $('#searchMe').height;
$('div.outer').height = 0.5*tableHeight
```